# Select the last row with a value less than another's table value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables

Transactions

| tx_id | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 150 | 10000 |
| 100 | 7000 |
| 50 | 5000 |

Premium

| since_tx_id | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | 10 |
| 45 | 5 |

I'd like to get the premium rate for each item on the Transactions table. The result should look like this:

| tx_id | cost | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 150 | 10000 | 10 |
| 100 | 7000 | 5 |
| 50 | 5000 | 5 |

So the rate for each of the Transactions would be the nearest (previous) since_tx_id value from the Previous table.

I've tried with a INNER JOIN using a ROW_NUMBER() but it didn't work and I've also tried using the MAX operator, both with no good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `lead()` and then a `join`:

```
select t.*, p.rate
from transactions t join
     (select p.*,
             lead(since_tx_id) over (order by since_tx_id) as next_ since_tx_id
      from premium p
     ) p
     on t.tx_id >= since_tx_id and
        (t.tx_id < next_since_tx_id or next_since_tx_id is null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT` join of the tables and `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*,
       FIRST_VALUE(p.rate) OVER (PARTITION BY t.tx_id ORDER BY p.since_tx_id DESC) rate
FROM Transactions t LEFT JOIN Premium p
ON p.since_tx_id <= t.tx_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=191c113367a5647f44c2d3a67e6e6ee6).